# ${1\over 2}\cdot{3\over 4}\dotsm{2n-1\over 2n}<{1\over \sqrt{3n+1}}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I need to show my Induction

${1\over 2}\cdot{3\over 4}\dotsm{2n-1\over 2n}<{1\over \sqrt{3n+1}}$

$P(2)={1\over 2}{3\over 4}<{1\over\sqrt{7}}$,
Which is true,

$p(k)<{1\over \sqrt{3k+1}}$

Now I am not able to show $p(k+1)<{1\over \sqrt{3k+4}}$

Thank you