# Prove: $\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{2}{3}\cdots\frac{2n-1}{2n}<\frac{1}{\sqrt{2n+1}}$

Tags: inequality, products

prove the inequality if you can: $\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{2}{3}\cdots\frac{2n-1}{2n}<\frac{1}{\sqrt{2n+1}}$

Thanks.

Comment: Hint: $LHS=\frac{1}{2n}$.

Comment: Are you sure the second factor on the left isn't supposed to be $\frac34$ instead of $\frac23$?

Comment: Some other questions about the same inequality:
http://math.stackexchange.com/q/431234
http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1940425
http://math.stackexchange.com/q/2078166

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\frac{1}{2}<\frac{2}{3},$$
$$\frac{3}{4}<\frac{4}{5},$$
$$.........................$$
$$\frac{2n-1}{2n}<\frac{2n}{2n+1},$$
$$\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{3}{4}\cdots\frac{2n-1}{2n}<\frac{2}{3}\cdot\frac{4}{5}\cdots\frac{2n}{2n+1}/\cdot \left(\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{3}{4}\cdots\frac{2n-1}{2n}\right)$$
$$\left(\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{3}{4}\cdots\frac{2n-1}{2n}\right)^2<\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{3}{4}\cdots\frac{2n-1}{2n}\cdot \frac{2}{3}\cdot\frac{4}{5}\cdots\frac{2n}{2n+1}$$
$$\left(\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{3}{4}\cdots\frac{2n-1}{2n}\right)^2<\frac{1}{2n+1}$$
$$\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{3}{4}\cdots\frac{2n-1}{2n}<\frac{1}{\sqrt{2n+1}}$$

Comment: The factor $\frac23$ on the left is a typo for $\frac34$, isn't it? The left side of the inequality is supposed to be $\Pi_{k=1}^n\frac{2k-1}{2k}$, I guess?

Comment: for me as I do not understand very well inequalities seems understandable with the above solution, thanks sir

Answer (score 3):

I assume that $n$ is a integer positive number.
Then:

$$\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{2}{3}\cdots\frac{2n-1}{2n} = \frac{(2n-1)!}{(2n)!} = \frac{1}{2n} < \frac{1}{\sqrt{2n+1}}$$

$$\sqrt{2n+1}<2n$$
$$2n+1 < 4n^2$$
$$4n^2-2n-1>0$$

Real solutions of $4n^2-2n-1=0$ are $n=\frac{1 \pm \sqrt{5}}{4}$ ($n=0.809...$, $n=-0.309...$).
This parabola is always positive for every number greater than $n=0.809$ and hence it is satisfied for every integer $n\geq1$.

Comment: Another way to see that the inequality always hold is to note that $2n+1 < 4n^2$ for $n=1$, and that the right-hand-side increases much faster than the left-hand side.