# Prove $\frac{1\cdot 3\cdots(2n-1)}{2\cdot 4 \cdots(2n)}<\frac{1}{\sqrt{2n+1}}$, $n\ge 1$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, induction, factorial, radicals

Prove $\frac{1\cdot 3\cdots(2n-1)}{2\cdot 4 \cdots(2n)}<\frac{1}{\sqrt{2n+1}}$, $n\ge 1$.

I begin by letting $n=1$ then $\frac{1}{2}<\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$. Then assume  $\frac{1\cdot 3\cdots(2k-1)}{2\cdot 4 \cdots(2k)}<\frac{1}{\sqrt{2k+1}}$,  for some $k\ge 1$. Then if I multiply both sides by $\frac{(2(k+1)-1)}{2(k+1)}$ I get $\frac{1\cdot 3\cdots(2(k+1)-1)}{2\cdot 4 \cdots2(k+1)}<\frac{1}{\sqrt{2k+1}}\cdot \frac{(2(k+1)-1)}{2(k+1)}$. So I have what I need on the left hand side, but I'm not sure how to continue on the right hand side. I realized that if I show that $\frac{(2(k+1)-1)}{2(k+1)}<\frac{\sqrt{2k+1}}{\sqrt{2(k+1)+1}}$ then I would be done. This however leads to the same dilemma in that I can easily make the left the way I need, but not the right. So there must be a trick that I am missing.

Comment: Have you tried cross-multiplying, squaring, and simplifying to check whether or not $\frac{2(k+1)-1}{2(k+1)} < \frac{\sqrt{2k+1}}{\sqrt{2(k+1)+1}}$? This would be the most direct way to continue your argument.

Comment: What @Dan said. You might want to put $j=k+1$ to simplify the algebra.

Comment: I will work on that, I was looking for a much more implicit trick and failed to see the obvious one

Comment: @Burgundy: It's straightforward to show that $\frac{2x-1}{2x} < \frac{\sqrt{2x-1}}{\sqrt{2x+1}}$ (which is what you have) directly for $x = k+1$ and $k$ a natural number. You could also try something slicker, *e.g.*, noting that $2\cdot 4 \cdots (2n) = 2^n n!$ or expanding the fractions into products like in the answer below, but I was attempting to help you finish your argument. All are valid options. `:)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the inductive step: from
$\;\dfrac{1\cdot 3\cdots(2n-1)}{2\cdot 4 \cdots(2n)}<\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2n+1}}$, you deduce
$$\dfrac{1\cdot 3\cdots(2n-1)(2n+1)}{2\cdot 4 \cdots(2n)(2n+2)}<\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2n+1}}\frac{2n+1}{2n+2},$$
hence it is enough to prove $\;\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2n+1}}\dfrac{2n+1}{2n+2}<\dfrac1{\sqrt{2n+3}}$. This is equivalent to
$$\sqrt{(2n+1)(2n+3)}<2n+2,$$
which is the A.G.M. inequality (case of *strict* inequality).

Answer (score 3):

First observe that
$$\frac{2n-1}{2n}<\frac{2n}{2n+1}\qquad\text{since }(2n-1)(2n+1)=4n^2-1<4n^2=(2n)(2n)$$
Then
\begin{align}
\left(\prod_{k=1}^{n}\frac{2k-1}{2k}\right)^2&<\left(\prod_{k=1}^{n}\frac{2k-1}{2k}\right)\left(\prod_{k=1}^{n}\frac{2k}{2k+1}\right)\\
&=\prod_{k=1}^{n}\frac{2k-1}{2k+1}\qquad\text{this product is "telescopic"}\\
&=\frac{1}{2n+1}
\end{align}
So
$$\prod_{k=1}^{n}\frac{2k-1}{2k}<\frac{1}{\sqrt{2n+1}}$$